# Excel Escape 2 ""

Tags: excel, escaping

> & CHAR(10) & REPT(" ", 20)& "5. Change object BusinessCardRequest(FirstName=$CreatedFor/FirstName;LastName=$CreatedFor/Surname;EmailAddress=$CreatedFor/Email;MobileNumber=$CreatedFor/Mobile;PositionTitle=if $PositionFirst != empty then $PositionFirst/Title  else "" "";Brand=if $PositionFirst != empty then getCaption($PositionFirst/Brand) else "" "")"

I have above code in excel and I want to escape so that I show 2 empty string as value for If condition. But it gives error I tried using 3 like `""" """` it is also not working. But when I remove one it works.

How to correctly escape 2 `" "` in excel

Comment: If, as you say it works, then do that...

Comment: Use CHR(34) ? `Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34)`

Comment: @SolarMike I need both entries. So deleting one is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to escape a " in Excel is to add one more " before it.

By escaping a " you are asking Excel to treat it as literal text.

---

***For example:***

```
"The ""fox"" jumped over the lazy dog"
```

would evaluate as

```
The "fox" jumped over the lazy dog
```

---

In answer to your example below:

> But it gives error I tried using 3 like """ """ it is also not working. But when I remove one it works.

You don't have to encase the problematic character in escape characters, you only need to immediately precede the problematic character with the escape character.

Comment: I notice that even removing all the "" "" i still get the error is there a limit to characters in a cell? maybe that is one reason?

Comment: @Martin yes, there is a limit to characters, and another limit to the number of nested functions in one formula. It looks like the above formula you've shared with us is already pretty large, and isn't the whole thing - so there is a good chance that's your problem.